# Commutators, Unitary Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $[a, a^\dagger]=aa^\dagger-a^\dagger a = 1$ and $[b, b^\dagger]=bb^\dagger-b^\dagger b = 1$

Show that:

$e^{\theta (a^\dagger b - b^\dagger a)}$ is unitary, where $\theta$ is a constant.

Comment: Can those voting to close please help this new user out by telling them how to improve their question?

Answer (score 2):

Let $k:=a^*b-b^*a$. Then $k^*=-k$. So, for every $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\theta k$ and $(\theta k)^*=-\theta k$ commute, whence
$$
e^{\theta k}e^{(\theta k)^*}=e^{(\theta k)^*}e^{\theta k}=e^{\theta k+ (\theta k)^*}=e^{\theta k-\theta k}=e^0=1. 
$$
Since $(e^{\theta k})^*=e^{(\theta k)^*}$, the latter proves that $u=e^{\theta k}$ is unitary.

**Note:** the assumptions $[a,a^*]=[b,b^*]=1$ are useless. But we need $\theta$ to be real in this argument.

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation was great!

Answer (score 2):

Your $\theta$ needs to be real for this to hold, and the conditions on the commutators are not needed.

Indeed, one can check explicitly that $(a^*b-b^*a)(b^*a-a^*b)=(b^*a-a^*b)(a^*b-b^*a)$, and so the product of the exponentials will be the exponential of the sum. So
$$
\left(e^{\theta(a^*b-b^*a)}\right)^*e^{\theta(a^*b-b^*a)}=e^{\theta(b^*a-a^*b)}e^{\theta(a^*b-b^*a)}=e^{\theta(b^*a-a^*b+a^*b-b^*a)}=e^0=I.
$$
The computation to show that $e^{\theta(a^*b-b^*a)}\left(e^{\theta(a^*b-b^*a)}\right)^*=I$ is completely similar.

What's happening here is that the exponent is skew-symmetric, i.e. it is an operator $y$ such that $y^*=-y$. This implies that $y$ is normal, i.e. $y^*y=-y^2=yy^*$, and so 
$$
(e^y)^*e^y=e^{-y}e^y=e^{-y+y}=e^0=I.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation was great! It added to my understanding from the previous response!

Comment: You are very welcome. I hope it is clear to you that in general the equality $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ does not hold; it does hold when $xy=yx$.

Comment: Yes, this is clear now. Thank you again!